# count no of rows in cake php base on email id

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

when i count no of rows in php i do like that

```
   $sql=mysql_query("select * from users where username='$email'") or die("select error".mysql_query());

   $no_rows=mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

but i dont know how to do it in cake php and my data is coming this from

```
[User] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => arjun
        [last_name] => tyagi
        [username] => arjun@gmail.com
        [phone_no] => 9569908024
        [mobile_no] => 9569908024
        [state_id] => 2
        [location_id] => 15
        [password] => cffa41a028807034b54b5849d5f4d3ca7532e701
        [confirm_password] => 12345
    )
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$totalUsers = $this->User->find('count', array('conditions'=>array('User.email' => $email)));
```

but that is actually pretty well documented:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the row count (with conditions) you should be looking for the [find('count') function](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1018/find#find-count-1020)

Answer (score 0):

For **CakePhp 3.x**  Getting a Count of Results,
Once you have created a query object, you can use the count() method to get a result count of that query:

```
// In a controller
$query = $this->users->find('all', [
   'conditions' => ['email' => 'youremail@domain.com']
]);
$number = $query->count();
```